# Naming convention for using reserved words as variable names in dart

Tags: dart, naming-conventions

What is the convention to name variables that were intended to be named as reserved words in dart? For example, I have this enum, ported from kotlin code:

```
enum DisplayType { string, $enum, number }
```

In the original kotlin code, enum consts were in all caps (`enum DisplayType { STRING, ENUM, NUMBER}`), as per kotlin's convention, but in dart, enum consts should be lower case (I get a warning if I try to make them all caps).

string and number are not reserved words, but enum is, so I had to rename enum const to $enum, inside the enum. Is this ok, or is there a better way to name consts/variables in situations like this?

Comment: In this case, I would probably go for `stringType`, `enumType` and `numberType` as the values of the `DisplayType` enum. Yeah, it is not pretty but I don't think it is too horrible either. :)

Comment: Why not use the unshortened equivalent: `enumeration`?